# Cannot load trace file using libtorch 1.5 in C++

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

After training a model, I created a trace file in Python side using Pytorch 1.5. I tried to load that file in C++ side using libtorch 1.5 writing that code:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    //Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
    torch::jit::script::Module module = torch::jit::load("D:/Downloads/deneme18.pt");
    module.to(torch::kCUDA);

}
```

It gave me this error message:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8C2A0A799 in DL_Predicton.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: c10::Error at memory location
>   0x0000009B6118EFE0."